# Detect coordinates on release of a swipe swift with spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer, swipe-gesture

Hi if someone can help me with this that would be great!

I need to get coordinates of a swipe. I can get the coordinates of the initial touch from locationInNode etc, however how can we get the coordinates on the release point of a swipe?

```
func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    touched = true

    for touch in touches {
        location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        print(location)
    }
}
```

This is how i get my initial coordinates, I have also done this for touchesMoved

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        print(location)
    }
```

with this code it does not print the final coordinate of release on touch.

Basically I would like to workout the distance between first touch and point on release of swipe with coordinates.
Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @Elliott Frisch it would be great if you can help me as I have just provided more details of my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the state of the swipe, from `began` to `ended`:

```
let point: CGPoint = recognizer.location(in: recognizer.view!)
if recognizer.state == .began {
    print(NSCoder.string(for: point))
}
else if recognizer.state == .ended {
    print(NSCoder.string(for: point))
}
```

Comment: rashwan thank you so much!!!

Comment: @prival, np glad to help!

Comment: i couldnt figure out where to put your code, I have tried under view did load, and initiated UIGestureRecognizer but it kept returning 0,0 as coordinates @Rashwan L

Comment: @prival place it in your `UIGesture` function. `let swipe = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "myFunc");
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true`. Place it in `myFunc` for example.

Answer (score 2):

```
-(IBAction)swipe:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    UIView *view1 = sender.view;

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
           CGPoint touchUpPoint = [sender locationInView:view1];
        NSLog(@"x=%f, y=%f",touchUpPoint.x,touchUpPoint.y);
    }

}
```